# GLFW does not recognize most controller models

Tags: c++, glfw

I am currently working on a game using C++ and OpenGL, and attempting to add controller support using GLFW (which we are already using for keyboard and mouse input).

Everything I have seen and read implies that all you need to do is plug in a controller and GLFW will recognize it and allow you to use it. After a bunch of trial and error, I have come to find that GLFW will only recognize one of the types of controllers I have.

I tried the following:

- Thrustmaster USB Joystick (a flight stick)
- Another joystick I don't know the model of (also a flight stick)
- Wired Xbox 360 Controller
- Xbox One Controller (plugged in via USB)
- PS4 Controller (plugged in via USB)

Out of all of these, only the PS4 controller was correctly recognized as a controller with joysticks. Am I doing something wrong or missing something? The other controllers all work fine otherwise and are usable in things like games I have on Steam, so I'm just not sure why it only recognizes the joysticks on the PS4 controller

Comment: What version of GLFW are you using?

Comment: 3.0.4 according to glfwGetVersionString. I didn't realize we were using an older version, so I'll try updating it

Comment: If you are on Windows then 3.2 and later should have better controller / joystick support.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that updating GLFW to 3.2 fixed the issue. We were previously using a package containing multiple other libraries that was very deprecated